# How to parse variables from a configuration file

Tags: ruby, variables

I have a configuration file that i want to parse and write in a new file in a different format.

i get the variables in this format

```
args([
"-key1 val1",
"-key2 2",
"-key3  true"
])
```

the keys are all strings, and the values can be string, bool, int.

is there way to parse this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, the following code will do:

```
ar = ["-key1 val1", "-key2 2", "-key3  true" ]
ar.map { |e| e =~ /\A-(\S+)\s+(.*)\z/ && [$1, $2] }.compact.to_h
#⇒ {
#  "key1" => "val1",
#  "key2" => "2",
#  "key3" => "true"
# }
```

There is no ability to convert types, besides guessing them. When the `-key value` lines are stored in the file:

```
File.readlines("path/to/file.cfg").map do |e|
  e =~ /\A-(\S+)\s+(.*)\z/ && [$1, $2]
end.compact.to_h
```

Comment: I reading the file that a user writes. the key values a gave are an example.
So i'm looking for something more generic. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “more generic”? While the file consists of `-key value` lines this code works pretty fine. Whether you expect another input, please specify it explicitly.